# turning my cell of doubles into an array of doubles

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, apache-poi, cell

I am taking the data from an excel file of every row in each specified column, using the row.getCell(); I want this data to be in an ArrayList. How do I go about converting the content of the Cell srs to and ArrayList.

```
for(Row row : sheet){
        if(row.getRowNum() == 0)
            continue;
        Cell Rk = row.getCell(2);
        Cell seed = row.getCell(1);
        Cell srs = row.getCell(7);


        System.out.println(srs);
This is what it prints
0.974
0.588
0.213
ect.
```

Comment: Are you using Apache POI? (i.e., is `Cell` an imported `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell`?)

Comment: Well, there's the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue())...

Comment: yes I am using the apache POI

Comment: Cell numbers = row.getCell(7);
double srs = numbers.getNumericCellValue();       Well I tried this but now I'm confused because the double srs is multiple different numbers?

Comment: figured it out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question I think you are looking for something like this:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(Row row : sheet){
    if(row.getRowNum() == 0)
        continue;
    Cell srs = row.getCell(7);
    list.add(src.getNumericCellValue());
}
```

The `getNumericCellValue()` returns the cell-value as native type `double`. Java auto-boxing will take care of converting it into an Object-type `Double`.

See [this guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) for some more details.